# Can not assign values to self properties from within a block

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a viewcontroller class and another class of NSObject. I call from the viewcontroller class with the following method the NSObject class.

SubmitContentViewController class

```
@implementation SubmitContentViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad{
[self callUploadQueueClass];
}

-(void)callUploadQueueClass{
UploadQueueClass *queue = [UploadQueueClass new]; 
[self generateIDforImage];
}

@end
```

UploadQueueClass

```
@implementation UploadQueueClass

    -(void)generateIDforImage{
        @weakify(self)
        [[[ApiServicesProvider shared] userService] getCreatorsContentID:^(NSDictionary * _Nullable result, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            @strongify(self)
            if(nil==error){
                NSString* ccID = result.creatorsContentId;
                self.creatorsContentID = ccID;
                NSLog(@"creatorsContentID %@",self.creatorsContentID);
             
                [self getImageUploadURL:ccID withNumberOfAttempts:10];
            }
            else{
                self.isUploading = NO;
            }
        }];
    }

@end
```

at this line

```
NSLog(@"creatorsContentID %@",self.creatorsContentID);
```

creatorsContentID is null although at this line

```
self.creatorsContentID = ccID;
```

ccID is not null so self.creatorsContentID should not be null.

Moreover at this line

```
[self getImageUploadURL:ccID withNumberOfAttempts:10];
```

is never get called.

What am i missing?

Comment: It seems likely that `self` is `nil` in the closure.

Comment: Why? Do i have to pass self inside the block?

Comment: Well, you have made `self` weak, so if whatever "owns" the block has been released, `self` will be nil.

Comment: Yes but then i use strongify(self) inside the block...

Comment: Strongify won't magically reinstate a released object. Set a breakpoint in your block and you will see that `self` is nil. You probably don't need to weak self dance here, but your bigger problem is why is the object itself going out of scope?  How do you call this function?

Comment: I call it directly from a viewcontroller class like UploadQueueClass *queue = [UploadQueueClass new]; [self generateIDforImage];

Comment: Could edit your question, and explain in which class is that method, and what's the call context: Where is created the object, what's its "lifespan". For instance, if you did `-(void)doTheThing { ThatClass *object = [[ThatClass alloc] init]; [object generateIDforImage]; }`, then `object` will be released before the completion happen. The `weak` allows you to avoid memory leak, it's true, but it means in reality, that it avoid "circular reference", making two objects to never get released, and then leak. That's the real mean behind that.

Comment: Yeah this is what i do inside the view controller class UploadQueueClass *queue = [UploadQueueClass new]; [self generateIDforImage]; What do you mean by saying what’s the call context? What do you mean where is created the object? (i mentioned inside the viewcontroller class) . What do you mean what is its lifespan? I want to call the method of this class to upload an image and when the upload completes then release the queue object.

Comment: Why you have mentioned `UploadQueueClass` which isn't used anywhere?

Comment: I updated my question so you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating your `UploadQueueClass` instance as a local variable `*queue` in `callUploadQueueClass`.

This local variable holds a strong reference to the `UploadQueueClass` instance.

As soon as the function returns, that local variable is released and it no longer holds the strong reference.

This happens *before* `getCreatorsContentID` has completed its work.  *Before* the completion handler block is called.

You have used `@weakify` so that the `self` captured by the block  does not hold a strong reference to the `UploadQueueClass` instance. The local variable has been released and the block `self` doesn't hold a strong reference to the instance.  Nothing does, so it is released.

The `self` in the block is now `nil`.  Using `@Strongify` won't help you here; the object has already gone away;

In this case you don't need to use `@weakify`; There is no danger of a circular reference causing a memory leak; The blocks capture of `self` only lasts until the completion handler has done its work.

However, removing `@weakify` doesn't seem like it would really help since there doesn't seem to be any way for the `UploadQueueClass` instance to communicate its results back to the calling view controller.

It would be more typical for the view controller to provide the completion handler block to the function it is calling, or at least provide *some* block to be executed.  This is where you could use `@weakify` since the view controller instance would be `self`, but the block doesn't need to hold a strong reference to it to keep it around; The view controller hierarchy is doing that.

Since you don't want this object to report back to the view controller, simply remove the `@weakify`/`@strongify`.  Then the block itself will hold a strong reference to the `UploadQueueClass` instance until it returns and then the object will be released by ARC.

Comment: I do not want to update the viewcontroller that the method is called from. I just want to do a background upload and save somedata to the nsuserdefaults. Is it ok to remove weakify and strongify?

Comment: Ok, you still need to do something to keep the `UploadQueueClass` instance around until its job is done. Simply removing `@weakify`/`@strongify` may be all you need.

Comment: Seems to be working if i remove the @weakify/@strongify and it works the upload until the job is done even if i navigate to another view or send the app in the background...is there a way to remove the instance when the upload completed? or ARC will do the job for me?

Comment: ARC will do the job for you; Once the block returns there is nothing holding a strong reference.

Comment: Sorry i am confused and trying to understand.

Comment: You are correct. Get rid of `@weakify` and ARC will clean up once the job is done.

Comment: Its working but now i need to update a different viewcontroller class other than SubmitContentViewController but i guess this is another question :)